# Java VM crashed when app memory reach 1.2G. Any way out?

Tags: native, jvm-crash

I am running automation testcase with long time soaking (from several hours to days). Whenever the memory usage reached about 1.2G, about 4 hours passed, the Java application will crash and the following err log file generated. The OS is windows, 64bits.

Did you encounter the same problem in you product? Could any giant do me a favor and give a way out?

Thank you in advance!

Frank

---

```
#
# An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (0xe06d7363), pid=2892, tid=3976
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (11.3-b02 mixed mode windows-x86)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0xb9bc]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x02659400):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=3976, stack(0x00090000,0x00190000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xe06d7363, ExceptionInformation=0x19930520 0x0018b014 0x7336aa04 

Registers:
EAX=0x0018af7c, EBX=0x72c9312c, ECX=0x00000003, EDX=0x00000000
ESP=0x0018af7c, EBP=0x0018afcc, ESI=0x0018b0b8, EDI=0x0018b0a8
EIP=0x76c0b9bc, EFLAGS=0x00000202

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0018af7c)
0x0018af7c:   e06d7363 00000001 00000000 76c0b9bc
0x0018af8c:   00000003 19930520 0018b014 7336aa04
0x0018af9c:   00000008 732d2e76 28a19088 0018b0a8
0x0018afac:   72c9312c 0018b0b8 0018afc0 732d24c4
0x0018afbc:   73376ba8 0018b000 732d17b7 00000008
0x0018afcc:   0018b004 732fc3ab e06d7363 00000001
0x0018afdc:   00000003 0018aff8 e06d7363 00000001
0x0018afec:   00000000 00000000 00000003 19930520 

Instructions: (pc=0x76c0b9bc)
0x76c0b9ac:   0c eb 03 89 45 c0 8d 45 b0 50 ff 15 5c 11 c0 76
0x76c0b9bc:   c9 c2 10 00 cc cc cc cc cc 8b ff 55 8b ec 56 8b 


Stack: [0x00090000,0x00190000],  sp=0x0018af7c,  free space=1003k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0xb9bc]
C  [MOZCRT19.dll+0x2c3ab]
C  [MOZCRT19.dll+0x34d93]
C  [xul.dll+0x2ccff3]
C  [xul.dll+0x592ca0]
C  [xul.dll+0x13077]
C  [js3250.dll+0x3a2e]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J  org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Lorg/eclipse/swt/internal/win32/MSG;)I
J  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch()Z
J  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Lorg/eclipse/jface/window/Window$IExceptionHandler;Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;)V
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI()I+555
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Lorg/eclipse/ui/internal/Workbench;)I+1
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run()V+55
j  org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Lorg/eclipse/core/databinding/observable/Realm;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+12
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;Lorg/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor;)I+18
j  org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;Lorg/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor;)I+2
j  com.xxx.svt.rcp.Application.runWorkbench()Ljava/lang/Integer;+13
j  com.xxx.svt.rcp.Application.start(Lorg/eclipse/equinox/app/IApplicationContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+567
j  org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+135
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+103
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+29
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+149
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run([Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)Ljava/lang/Object;+183
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+161
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework([Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/net/URL;)V+211
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun([Ljava/lang/String;)V+126
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run([Ljava/lang/String;)I+4
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x2600cc00 JavaThread "ExecutionThread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=3652, stack(0x27b50000,0x27b80000)]
  0x2600b000 JavaThread "Worker-35" [_thread_blocked, id=2696, stack(0x34ff0000,0x35020000)]
  0x2600d400 JavaThread "Worker-34" [_thread_blocked, id=2284, stack(0x33030000,0x33060000)]
  0x2b03a000 JavaThread "Worker-33" [_thread_blocked, id=3872, stack(0x32c10000,0x32c40000)]
  0x2b03b800 JavaThread "ExecutionThread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=2460, stack(0x2cab0000,0x2cae0000)]
  0x2600a400 JavaThread "ConsoleLoggerThread" [_thread_blocked, id=3604, stack(0x2c680000,0x2c6b0000)]
  0x2b03b400 JavaThread "Worker-32" [_thread_blocked, id=2188, stack(0x27500000,0x27530000)]
  0x24ead000 JavaThread "Worker-29" [_thread_blocked, id=2576, stack(0x43870000,0x438a0000)]
  0x24eb1c00 JavaThread "Timer-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3440, stack(0x2bfb0000,0x2bfe0000)]
  0x24eb3400 JavaThread "derby.rawStoreDaemon" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1448, stack(0x2c590000,0x2c5c0000)]
  0x24eb2c00 JavaThread "Thread-15" [_thread_blocked, id=2496, stack(0x2c520000,0x2c550000)]
  0x24eb2800 JavaThread "Worker-6" [_thread_blocked, id=3232, stack(0x2bfe0000,0x2c010000)]
  0x24eae400 JavaThread "Thread-13" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3904, stack(0x2bf40000,0x2bf70000)]
  0x24eb1800 JavaThread "Timer-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3840, stack(0x2ac10000,0x2ac40000)]
  0x24eb1000 JavaThread "derby.rawStoreDaemon" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2556, stack(0x2aa80000,0x2aab0000)]
  0x24eb0c00 JavaThread "Timer-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3948, stack(0x2a8a0000,0x2a8d0000)]
  0x24eb0400 JavaThread "derby.antiGC" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2620, stack(0x2a870000,0x2a8a0000)]
  0x24eb0000 JavaThread "Timer-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2584, stack(0x2a800000,0x2a830000)]
  0x24eaf800 JavaThread "29059446@qtp-19860713-1 - Acceptor0 SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:64365" [_thread_in_native, id=2924, stack(0x2a4a0000,0x2a4d0000)]
  0x24eaf400 JavaThread "28149392@qtp-19860713-0" [_thread_blocked, id=3768, stack(0x29850000,0x29880000)]
  0x24eae800 JavaThread "Bundle File Closer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3972, stack(0x287c0000,0x287f0000)]
  0x24ead800 JavaThread "Workspace server" [_thread_in_native, id=3088, stack(0x27bc0000,0x27bf0000)]
  0x24eacc00 JavaThread "Workspace monitor" [_thread_blocked, id=3404, stack(0x27ae0000,0x27b10000)]
  0x26069800 JavaThread "Fanfare Heartbeat" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3816, stack(0x26460000,0x26490000)]
  0x24e86800 JavaThread "Worker-JM" [_thread_blocked, id=2600, stack(0x25950000,0x25980000)]
  0x24dab000 JavaThread "[ThreadPool Manager] - Idle Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2936, stack(0x258b0000,0x258e0000)]
  0x24e4d000 JavaThread "[Timer] - Main Queue Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2804, stack(0x25920000,0x25950000)]
  0x24daa400 JavaThread "Framework Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2444, stack(0x25840000,0x25870000)]
  0x24dc7800 JavaThread "Start Level Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2740, stack(0x257d0000,0x25800000)]
  0x24dc7000 JavaThread "State Data Manager" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3776, stack(0x24f00000,0x24f30000)]
  0x02549400 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3336, stack(0x24b90000,0x24bc0000)]
  0x02543c00 JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=548, stack(0x24a50000,0x24b50000)]
  0x02543800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2104, stack(0x249e0000,0x24a10000)]
  0x02538c00 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3004, stack(0x24970000,0x249a0000)]
  0x02501000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2776, stack(0x24900000,0x24930000)]
  0x024fc800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=696, stack(0x01d70000,0x01da0000)]
=>0x02659400 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=3976, stack(0x00090000,0x00190000)]

Other Threads:
  0x024f7c00 VMThread [stack: 0x24800000,0x24900000] [id=2588]
  0x02552c00 WatcherThread [stack: 0x24c00000,0x24d00000] [id=2256]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 9216K, used 2445K [0x04660000, 0x05050000, 0x05a10000)
  eden space 8256K,  23% used [0x04660000, 0x0484cc08, 0x04e70000)
  from space 960K,  49% used [0x04e70000, 0x04ee69c0, 0x04f60000)
  to   space 960K,   0% used [0x04f60000, 0x04f60000, 0x05050000)
 tenured generation   total 121024K, used 42844K [0x05a10000, 0x0d040000, 0x14660000)
   the space 121024K,  35% used [0x05a10000, 0x083e70a8, 0x083e7200, 0x0d040000)
 compacting perm gen  total 131072K, used 64856K [0x14660000, 0x1c660000, 0x24660000)
   the space 131072K,  49% used [0x14660000, 0x185b6380, 0x185b6400, 0x1c660000)
No shared spaces configured.

Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x0040d000     C:\Program Files (x86)\xxxxxxxxxx\ttttt 4.2\ttttt.exe
0x77b80000 - 0x77d00000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
0x76db0000 - 0x76ec0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
0x76c00000 - 0x76c46000     C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
0x752f0000 - 0x753f0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
0x754e0000 - 0x75570000     C:\Windows\syswow64\GDI32.dll
0x75860000 - 0x7586a000     C:\Windows\syswow64\LPK.dll
0x755b0000 - 0x7564d000     C:\Windows\syswow64\USP10.dll
0x76c50000 - 0x76cfc000     C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
0x77220000 - 0x772c0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\ADVAPI32.dll
0x768a0000 - 0x768b9000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
0x753f0000 - 0x754e0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\RPCRT4.dll
0x75260000 - 0x752c0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SspiCli.dll
0x75250000 - 0x7525c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x733e0000 - 0x73464000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.17514_none_ec83dffa859149af\COMCTL32.dll
0x77190000 - 0x771f0000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x76b30000 - 0x76bfc000     C:\Windows\syswow64\MSCTF.dll
0x72000000 - 0x7200d000     C:\Program Files (x86)\xxxxxxxxxx\ttttt 4.2\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.1.R36x_v20100810\eclipse_1309.dll
0x73970000 - 0x73979000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x6d800000 - 0x6da56000     C:\Program Files (x86)\xxxxxxxxxx\ttttt 4.2\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x736c0000 - 0x736f2000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x7c340000 - 0x7c396000     C:\Program Files (x86)\xxxxxxxxxx\ttttt 4.2\jre\bin\MSVCR71.dll
0x6e350000 - 0x6e39c000     C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x6d290000 - 0x6d298000     C:\Program Files (x86)\xxxxxxxxxx\ttttt 4.2\jre\bin\hpi.dll
0x768c0000 - 0x768c5000     C:\Windows\syswow64\PSAPI.DLL
0x6d7b0000 - 0x6d7bc000     C:\Program Files (x86)\xxxxxxxxxx\ttttt 4.2\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x6d330000 - 0x6d34f000     C:\Program Files (x86)\xxxxxxxxxx\ttttt 4.2\jre\bin\java.dll
0x6d7f0000 - 0x6d7ff000     C:\Program Files (x86)\xxxxxxxxxx\ttttt 4.2\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x71fa0000 - 0x71fb6000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x71db0000 - 0x71deb000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x734d0000 - 0x734e7000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x73a00000 - 0x73a0b000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x6d610000 - 0x6d623000     C:\Program Files (x86)\xxxxxxxxxx\ttttt 4.2\jre\bin\net.dll
0x75570000 - 0x755a5000     C:\Windows\syswow64\WS2_32.dll
0x76b20000 - 0x76b26000     C:\Windows\syswow64\NSI.dll
0x70f90000 - 0x70fcc000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x6f3a0000 - 0x6f3a6000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x70670000 - 0x70680000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x739d0000 - 0x739e0000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x739b0000 - 0x739c2000     C:\Windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x6f370000 - 0x6f397000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live\WLIDNSP.DLL
0x75650000 - 0x756a7000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SHLWAPI.dll
0x72070000 - 0x720b4000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x739e0000 - 0x739e8000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x710a0000 - 0x710a5000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x73950000 - 0x7396c000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x73940000 - 0x73947000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x6f2e0000 - 0x6f2e6000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x6f2a0000 - 0x6f2d8000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x73b40000 - 0x73bc0000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x76f10000 - 0x7706c000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x6d630000 - 0x6d639000     C:\Program Files (x86)\xxxxxxxxxx\ttttt 4.2\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x77100000 - 0x7718f000     C:\Windows\syswow64\OLEAUT32.DLL
0x26310000 - 0x26373000     C:\Program Files (x86)\xxxxxxxxxx\ttttt 4.2\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\527\1\.cp\swt-win32-3655.dll
0x75870000 - 0x758eb000     C:\Windows\syswow64\comdlg32.dll
0x73bc0000 - 0x73d5e000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2\COMCTL32.dll
0x75a90000 - 0x766da000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SHELL32.dll
0x756b0000 - 0x757cb000     C:\Windows\syswow64\WININET.dll
0x77b50000 - 0x77b53000     C:\Windows\syswow64\Normaliz.dll
0x766e0000 - 0x76898000     C:\Windows\syswow64\iertutil.dll
0x76a00000 - 0x76b11000     C:\Windows\syswow64\urlmon.dll
0x73470000 - 0x73483000     C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
0x24fd0000 - 0x24fed000     C:\Program Files (x86)\xxxxxxxxxx\ttttt 4.2\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\527\1\.cp\swt-gdip-win32-3655.dll
0x73700000 - 0x73890000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.7601.17825_none_72d273598668a06b\gdiplus.dll
0x25300000 - 0x2530e000     C:\Program Files (x86)\xxxxxxxxxx\ttttt 4.2\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\371\1\.cp\os\win32\x86\localfile_1_0_0.dll
0x267d0000 - 0x26993000     C:\Program Files (x86)\xxxxxxxxxx\ttttt 4.2\plugins\com.xxx.svt.configuration.licensing.flexlm.nativeprovider.win32_4.2.0.64338\flexlm\lmgr11.dll
0x736a0000 - 0x736b1000     C:\Windows\system32\NETAPI32.dll
0x739a0000 - 0x739a9000     C:\Windows\system32\netutils.dll
0x73980000 - 0x73999000     C:\Windows\system32\srvcli.dll
0x73690000 - 0x7369f000     C:\Windows\system32\wkscli.dll
0x73680000 - 0x73687000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x734f0000 - 0x7352c000     C:\Windows\system32\oleacc.dll
0x272d0000 - 0x274c0000     C:\Program Files (x86)\xxxxxxxxxx\ttttt 4.2\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\224\1\.cp\flexlm_license.dll
0x71090000 - 0x7109d000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
0x70f70000 - 0x70f82000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
0x73670000 - 0x73673000     C:\Windows\system32\icmp.Dll
0x73630000 - 0x73659000     C:\Windows\system32\WINSTA.dll
0x73a40000 - 0x73b35000     C:\Windows\system32\propsys.dll
0x77070000 - 0x770f3000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CLBCatQ.DLL
0x6ef60000 - 0x6f0cf000     C:\Windows\system32\explorerframe.dll
0x6ef30000 - 0x6ef5f000     C:\Windows\system32\DUser.dll
0x6ee70000 - 0x6ef22000     C:\Windows\system32\DUI70.dll
0x71f90000 - 0x71f9e000     C:\Windows\system32\RpcRtRemote.dll
0x288a0000 - 0x288b3000     C:\Program Files (x86)\xxxxxxxxxx\ttttt 4.2\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\527\1\.cp\swt-xulrunner-win32-3655.dll
0x73380000 - 0x733aa000     C:\Program Files (x86)\xxxxxxxxxx\ttttt 4.2\plugins\org.mozilla.xulrunner.win32.x86_1.9.1.15\xulrunner\nspr4.dll
0x732d0000 - 0x7337f000     C:\Program Files (x86)\xxxxxxxxxx\ttttt 4.2\plugins\org.mozilla.xulrunner.win32.x86_1.9.1.15\xulrunner\MOZCRT19.dll
0x73620000 - 0x73627000     C:\Program Files (x86)\xxxxxxxxxx\ttttt 4.2\plugins\org.mozilla.xulrunner.win32.x86_1.9.1.15\xulrunner\plc4.dll
0x73660000 - 0x73667000     C:\Program Files (x86)\xxxxxxxxxx\ttttt 4.2\plugins\org.mozilla.xulrunner.win32.x86_1.9.1.15\xulrunner\plds4.dll
0x73250000 - 0x732c3000     C:\Program Files (x86)\xxxxxxxxxx\ttttt 4.2\plugins\org.mozilla.xulrunner.win32.x86_1.9.1.15\xulrunner\sqlite3.dll
0x733c0000 - 0x733d4000     C:\Program Files (x86)\xxxxxxxxxx\ttttt 4.2\plugins\org.mozilla.xulrunner.win32.x86_1.9.1.15\xulrunner\nssutil3.dll
0x73220000 - 0x73246000     C:\Program Files (x86)\xxxxxxxxxx\ttttt 4.2\plugins\org.mozilla.xulrunner.win32.x86_1.9.1.15\xulrunner\softokn3.dll
0x72d80000 - 0x72e1d000     C:\Program Files (x86)\xxxxxxxxxx\ttttt 4.2\plugins\org.mozilla.xulrunner.win32.x86_1.9.1.15\xulrunner\nss3.dll
0x731f0000 - 0x73211000     C:\Program Files (x86)\xxxxxxxxxx\ttttt 4.2\plugins\org.mozilla.xulrunner.win32.x86_1.9.1.15\xulrunner\ssl3.dll
0x731d0000 - 0x731e8000     C:\Program Files (x86)\xxxxxxxxxx\ttttt 4.2\plugins\org.mozilla.xulrunner.win32.x86_1.9.1.15\xulrunner\smime3.dll
0x72f40000 - 0x7300c000     C:\Program Files (x86)\xxxxxxxxxx\ttttt 4.2\plugins\org.mozilla.xulrunner.win32.x86_1.9.1.15\xulrunner\js3250.dll
0x72430000 - 0x72d7e000     C:\Program Files (x86)\xxxxxxxxxx\ttttt 4.2\plugins\org.mozilla.xulrunner.win32.x86_1.9.1.15\xulrunner\xul.dll
0x723d0000 - 0x72421000     C:\Windows\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
0x73490000 - 0x73495000     C:\Windows\system32\MSIMG32.dll
0x733b0000 - 0x733b7000     C:\Program Files (x86)\xxxxxxxxxx\ttttt 4.2\plugins\org.mozilla.xulrunner.win32.x86_1.9.1.15\xulrunner\xpcom.dll
0x73610000 - 0x73618000     C:\Program Files (x86)\xxxxxxxxxx\ttttt 4.2\plugins\org.mozilla.xulrunner.win32.x86_1.9.1.15\xulrunner\javaxpcomglue.dll
0x723b0000 - 0x723ce000     C:\Windows\system32\t2embed.dll
0x708c0000 - 0x709bb000     C:\Windows\system32\WindowsCodecs.dll
0x72330000 - 0x72361000     C:\Windows\system32\EhStorShell.dll
0x758f0000 - 0x75a8d000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SETUPAPI.dll
0x771f0000 - 0x77217000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CFGMGR32.dll
0x76d60000 - 0x76d72000     C:\Windows\syswow64\DEVOBJ.dll
0x72250000 - 0x722c0000     C:\Windows\system32\ntshrui.dll
0x72f30000 - 0x72f3b000     C:\Windows\system32\cscapi.dll
0x723a0000 - 0x723aa000     C:\Windows\system32\slc.dll
0x6f190000 - 0x6f1be000     C:\Windows\system32\mlang.dll
0x72380000 - 0x7238f000     C:\Program Files (x86)\xxxxxxxxxx\ttttt 4.2\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\374\1\.cp\jWinHttp-1.0.0.dll
0x70e30000 - 0x70e88000     C:\Windows\system32\WINHTTP.dll
0x70de0000 - 0x70e2f000     C:\Windows\system32\webio.dll
0x71200000 - 0x71208000     C:\Windows\system32\credssp.dll
0x6d560000 - 0x6d569000     C:\Program Files (x86)\xxxxxxxxxx\ttttt 4.2\jre\bin\management.dll
0x2bc80000 - 0x2bcd5000     C:\Users\Gavin\AppData\Local\Temp\jna2783130979677457687.dll
0x768e0000 - 0x769fe000     C:\Windows\syswow64\Crypt32.dll
0x768d0000 - 0x768dc000     C:\Windows\syswow64\MSASN1.dll
0x72370000 - 0x72373000     C:\Windows\system32\Security.dll
0x73a10000 - 0x73a31000     C:\Windows\system32\ntmarta.dll
0x76ec0000 - 0x76f05000     C:\Windows\syswow64\WLDAP32.dll
0x722f0000 - 0x72308000     C:\Program Files (x86)\xxxxxxxxxx\ttttt 4.2\plugins\org.mozilla.xulrunner.win32.x86_1.9.1.15\xulrunner\nssdbm3.dll
0x72200000 - 0x72241000     C:\Program Files (x86)\xxxxxxxxxx\ttttt 4.2\plugins\org.mozilla.xulrunner.win32.x86_1.9.1.15\xulrunner\freebl3.dll
0x721a0000 - 0x721f2000     C:\Program Files (x86)\xxxxxxxxxx\ttttt 4.2\plugins\org.mozilla.xulrunner.win32.x86_1.9.1.15\xulrunner\nssckbi.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xms128M -Xmx256M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:PermSize=128M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Xss192k 
java_command: <unknown>
Launcher Type: generic

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/xxxxxxxxxx/ttttt 4.2/jre/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/xxxxxxxxxx/ttttt 4.2/jre/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/xxxxxxxxxx/ttttt 4.2/jre/lib/i386;C:\Tcl\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Ixia;C:\Tcl\lib;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\xxxxxxxxxx\ttttt 4.2;C:\Program Files (x86)\xxxxxxxxxx\ttttt 4.2\tttttRT
USERNAME=someguy
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows NT 6.1 Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 2 (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 7 stepping 10, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3

Memory: 4k page, physical 4158712k(1651220k free), swap 4194303k(4194303k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (11.3-b02) for windows-x86 JRE (1.6.0_13-b03), built on Mar  9 2009 01:15:24 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 7.1

time: Fri Nov 23 11:13:12 2012
elapsed time: 74247 seconds
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem completely, but you can try increasing jvm heap size. Try running the program with -Xmx2g as jvm argument.

Comment: "-Xms128M -Xmx256M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:PermSize=128M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Xss192k" // These args are used. But the err log file didn't indicate the heap size out of memory. Any comments? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Actually, on 64 bit system, the max memory of each process should be 2G.

Comment: Yes, but in a 2GB process space the amount of contiguous space available for data will be less than 2G.